# Unable to update document.body based on scrollY in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I've got the following script on my site, intended to change the body class when the user scrolls more than 20px away from the top of the viewport.

```
(function ($) {
/// Make nav opaque on scroll
     window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      document.body.classList[
         window.scrollY > 20 ? 'add': 'remove'
      ]('scrolled');
     });
})(jQuery);
```

It works perfectly on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not on IE11.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN, IE11 does not support [window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY). Instead you could use `window.pageYOffset`, which is an alias for `window.scrollY`.

As mentioned on MDN,

> The pageYOffset property is an alias for the scrollY property:
>
> ```
> window.pageYOffset == window.scrollY; // always true
> ```
>
> For cross-browser compatibility, use window.pageYOffset instead of
>   window.scrollY. Additionally, older versions of Internet Explorer (<
>   9) do not support either property and must be worked around by
>   checking other non-standard properties. A fully compatible example:
>
> ```
> var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
> var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");
>
> var x = supportPageOffset ? window.pageXOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
> var y = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
> ```

In your case if you intend to support IE 11, you can directly replace `scrollY` with `pageYOffset`:

```
document.body.classList[
     window.pageYOffset > 20 ? 'add': 'remove'
  ]('scrolled');
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wg3nj06h/2/